# Firebase data and unexpected nil

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My ultimate goal is to display annotations on a Map from MapKit. However, loading data from firebase does not work. 
Here is the code:

```
var hotels = [Hotel]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    map.delegate = self
    checkLocationServices()
    observe()
}
```

The function observe is the following:

```
func observe() {
        Data().getAllHotel { (hotelA) -> (Void) in
            if let hotel = hotelA {
                print("hotel: ", hotel)
                self.hotels.append(hotel)
                let hotelAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
                hotelAnnotation.title = "\(hotel.hotelName)"
                hotelAnnotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: hotel.latitude, longitude: hotel.longitude)
                self.map.addAnnotation(hotelAnnotation)
            }
        }
}
```

Note that the print in the if statement is not empty. 
However the line `hotelAnnotation.title` causes a bug unexpected nil and I don't understand why.

Additionnally here is the `getAllHotel` function inside the Data class:

```
func getAllHotel(closure: HotelClosure?) {
        let ref = Ref().databaseHotels
        ref.observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
            if let dict = snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                let hotel = self.fromDictToHotel(key: snapshot.key, dict: dict)
                closure?(hotel)
            } else {
                closure?(nil)
            }
        }
    }

    func fromDictToHotel(key: String, dict: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>) -> Hotel? {
        guard let hotelName = dict["name"] as? String else { return nil }
        guard let latitude = dict["latitude"] as? Double else { return nil }
        guard let longitude = dict["longitude"] as? Double else { return nil }
        let hotelDescription = dict["description"] as? String
        let hotelGrade = dict["grade"] as? Double
        let hotelImageUrl = dict["hotelImageUrl"] as? String

        let hotel = Hotel(hid: key, hotelName: hotelName, hotelDescription: hotelDescription, latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude, grade: hotelGrade, url: hotelImageUrl)
        return hotel
    }
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Did you verify `hotel.hotelName` is valid and not nil?

Comment: Can you show an example of what the results of your print statement in `getAllHotel` are? Also, is `hotelName` forced unwrapped (eg: `var hotelName: String!`) in the Hotel definition? If you set a breakpoint in line 4 of `observe()` and type `po hotel.hotelName` when the break occurs, what is the output?

Comment: @Jay hotel.hotelName is not suppose to be nil if some hotel is printed as in the definition of hotel, the name is not optional

Comment: @Zoe, The output from console is ```hotel:  ProjectName.Hotel
Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value:...``` I added the ! on var hotelName, latitude and longitude in the Hotel definition, and now the error is on hotelAnnotation.coordinate line but same problem

Comment: Hey everyone, I figured out what was the problem. Hotel is a subclass of Item. Hence printing hotelName is nil but printing itemName is not nil. Sorry for that, it was a conception error !

Comment: Glad you figured it out!